# Ocaml evaluate boolean list to single boolean

Tags: list, pattern-matching, ocaml

when trying to write a simple program for solving a toy SAT problem, I came across the following problem I cannot get my head around.

I have a type variable which is defined as follows:

```
type prefix =
     | Not
     | None

type variable = 
     | Fixed of (prefix * bool)
     | Free of (prefix * string)
```

from which I can build a clause of type  variable list and a formula of type clause list. Essentially this boils down to having a formula in 
either CNF or DNF (this has less to do with the problem). 
When now trying to simplify a clause I do the following:

- Filter all Fixed variables from the clause which gives a list
- Simplify the variables (Fixed(Not, true) => Fixed(None, false))

Now I have a list containing just Fixed variables which I now want to combine to a single Fixed value by doing something like this

```
let combine l =
    match l with
    | [] -> []
    | [x] -> [x]
    | (* Get the first two variables, OR/AND them 
         and recurse on the rest of the list *)
```

How would I achieve my desired behavior in a functional language? My experience in OCaml is not that big, I am rather a beginner. 
I tried doing x::xs::rest -> x <||> xs <||> combine rest but this does not work. Where <||> is just a custom operator to OR the variables.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the neat higher order functions already there?

```
let combine = function
  | x::xs -> List.fold_left (<||>) x xs
  | [] -> failwith "darn, what do I do if the list is empty?"
```

For clarification:

```
List.fold_left : ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a
```

takes a function that gets the *running aggregate* and the next element of the list; it returns the *new aggregate*; then we need an initial value and the list of items to fold over.
The use of your infix operator `<||>` in brackets makes it a prefix function so we can give it to `List.fold_left` just like that -- instead of writing `(fun a b -> a <||> b)`.

If you have a neutral element of your `<||>` operator, lets call it `one`, we could write it even more concise:

```
let combine = List.fold_left (<||>) one
```

As `List.fold_left` requires three arguments and we only gave it two, `combine` here is a function of `variable list -> variable` as the previous one. If you wonder why this works, check out the concept of **currying**.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt:

```
let rec combine l =
    match l with
    | [] -> []
    | [x] -> [x]
    | a :: b :: rest -> combine ((a <||> b) :: rest)
```

Note you need `let rec`.